# SQLCipher Loadlibs and db password change

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

SQLCipher website mentions

"Init the database in onCreate() using SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this); //first init the db libraries with the context"

1. I am calling this loadlibs only once in my first activity (seems to be working). I want to make sure I do not need to call this function for every activity that might access the database. Is this correct?
2. How do I change the database password? I tried rekey but that does not work. It still takes the old password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct - you only need to call `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(...);` once as that is responsible for loading the various native libraries SQLCipher for Android uses at runtime into the process.  To change the password, you must first have a reference to a `SQLiteDatabase` object where you have provided the original password.  Once you have that you can issue `PRAGMA rekey = 'some new password';` using `execSQL(...);`.  More information regarding the rekey command can be found [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#rekey).

Comment: Are there any circumstances in which it would hurt anything to call `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs` more than once?

Answer (score 6):

```
SQLiteDatabase.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA key = 'old_password';");
SQLiteDatabase.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA rekey = 'new_password';");
```